# My function() Call Does Not Work On Mobile Phones

Tags: javascript, function, mobile

G'day All,

I'm hoping you can help me work out why my function() call in my "Blogger" post, only work on desktops and tablets but not on mobile phones?

I have put the below code into the head of my "Blogger" template and I call it into the post as indicated below. It works on desktops and Ipads displays but not on mobile phone displays.

If I remove the function() comand and insert the code directly into the post only, then it works on all devices so I don't understand why it doesn't work on mobiles with the function.

```
<!--MyAds Start-->
<script language="JavaScript">
<!-- Begin
var total_banner = 3;
var actual_time = new Date()
var second = actual_time.getSeconds()
var show_the_banner = second % total_banner;
show_the_banner +=1;
if (show_the_banner==1) {
txt="Comprehensive Babies, Parent - Teacher <br /> Swimming Lesson Plan";
url="http://www.swimteaching.com/2015/05/comprehensive-babies-parent-teacher.html";
alt="Image of a baby swimming";
banner="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-kH9zGxIMnxw/VTsVL8jwkwI/AAAAAAAABBI/a1sx-GrBsSE/s320/baby_child_swim.jpg";
width="250";
height="190";
}
if (show_the_banner==2) {
txt="Get Your Free<br />Swim Lesson Plans Here";
url="http://swimteaching.yolasite.com/lesson-plans-actual.php";
alt="Image of swim teacher helping a child float";
banner="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-GA8EJHSPug4/SOQFcHZ6oSI/AAAAAAAAAK0/eX7vsIalmfc/s320/FloatBackTeacherHead.jpg";
width="200";
height="100";
}
if (show_the_banner==3) {
txt="Get Your<br />Professional Swimming Lesson Plans<br />Here";
url="http://www.swimteaching.com/2015/04/professional-swiming-lesson-  plans.html";
alt="Image of swim teach teaching";
banner="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-2dpWzVuQqGg/Ux6h5Q2Ti_I/AAAAAAAAAvk/EjHf05GcRXc/s320/How%2Bto%2BFind%2Bthe%2BRight%2BSwim%2BTeacher%2Bfor%2BYour%2BChild%2527s%2BNeeds.JPG";
width="250";
height="100";
}
function myads(){
document.write('<center>');
document.write('<a href=\"' + url + '\" target=\"_top\">');
document.write('<img src=\"' + banner + '\" width=')
document.write(width + ' height=' + height + ' ');
document.write('alt=\"' + alt + '\" border=0><br>');
document.write('<large><strong>' + txt + '</strong></large></a>');
document.write('</center>');
}
// End -->
</script>
<!--MyAds End-->
```

Below Code inserted into post

```
<!--MyAds Start-->
<script language="JavaScript">
myads();
</script>
<!--MyAds End-->
```

Your help is appreciated
Richard

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onload=function(){
    myads();
}
```

Comment: While answers are always appreciated, it really helps to provide some information about how your code solves the problem at hand. Please provide some [context surrounding your answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259), and see the [help article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for information on how to write great answers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I wonder if you could give a bit more detail. as it stands I can't get that to work properly no matter where I put it.

Comment: I suspect the code has not been loaded, when your code at the time of the function call, so i try to call the function in the load event